# How to check state of flag in QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, flags, qtreewidget

I've just started to learn Qt.
I created QTreeWidget with flags and wanted new widget with text (for example) to be created after each check of flag. I tried to make vector of pointers to `ptwiC` to check condition later but there is no result.

```
QTreeWidget twg;
QVector<QTreeWidgetItem*> pointers;
QString lst;
    lst<< "Date"<< "Work"<< "Status";
    twg.setHeaderLabels(lst);

    QTreeWidgetItem* ptwi= new QTreeWidgetItem(&twg);
    ptwi->setText(0, "Works");

    QTreeWidgetItem* ptwiC= 0;
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            ptwiC= new QTreeWidgetItem(ptwi);
            ptwiC->setText(0, QString::number(i));
            ptwiC->setText(1, "Work"+ QString::number(i));
             ptwiC->setCheckState(2,Qt::Unchecked);
             pointers.push_back(ptwiC);
          }
             ptwi->setExpanded(true);

     twg.resize(400, 300);
     twg.show();

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    if(pointers[i]->checkState(2)==Qt::Checked){
          //some actions
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works for me perfectly fine.

```
bool TreeWidget_CheckedState::GetState(int buttonNr)
{
  return pointers.at(buttonNr)->checkState(2) == Qt::Checked;
}
```

[image]